# Stacked softmax layers before output

Tags: neural-networks, machine-learning

I have seen people using stacked softmax layers right at the output of neural networks designed for classification. I'm trying to understand this. Does it give any additional value? I think this could "sharpen" decisions on the boundaries.

> model.add(Dense(10, activation='sigmoid'))
>   model.add(Dense(1, 
>   activation='sigmoid'))

Seen [here.](https://github.com/natbusa/deepcredit/blob/master/default-prediction.ipynb)

Comment: could you give an example? i dont think this does anything